# When preprocessing Words in NLP, it changes the assumed numeric values after starting a new kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp

I'm using Anaconda Spyder as the editor( python 3.8),
my code is about to identify the phishing URLs based on NLP. Data was preprocessed using 'One hot representation' technique and trained using LSTM. after the training model gets around 90% accuracy. the problem is when I start a new kernel /after restarting the computer model does not give the accuracy as it gave in training.( problem doesn't occur when I use same kernel which used to train). I found that it is because every time I start a new kernel and preprocess data using 'One hot representation' it assumes different values.

ex- if google.com assumed as google = 1 and com = 2  when I use a new kernel it can be assumed as google = 5 and com = 6. so the model was trained using different values but prediction cannot do best because of value changing.

so is there any technique or technology which I can solve this problem. IF I can assume same value for every time I guess problem can be solved.

code used for preprocessing

```
url = 'https://www.google.com'
messages = urlparse(url).netloc  #taking only the domain name from URL

corpus=[]
voc_size = 10000

review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',messages)  #remove none a-z characters 
review = review.lower()
review = review.split()
review=' '.join(review)
corpus.append(review)


#assuming numerical values for words

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
onehot_repr=[one_hot(words,voc_size)for words in corpus]
print(onehot_repr)
```

If there is any technique of library that I can surpass this problem It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you insisted on using `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot` object the easiest way is to save/load vocabulary for reuse.

```
import pickle 
corpus = 'This is a test'.split()
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
onehot_repr=[one_hot(words,20)for words in corpus]
mapping = {c:o for c,o in zip(corpus, onehot_repr)}
print('Before', mapping)
with open('mapping.pkl', 'wb') as fout:
  pickle.dump(mapping, fout)
with open('mapping.pkl', 'rb') as fout:
  mapping = pickle.load(fout)
print('After', mapping)
```

output:

```
Before {'This': [3], 'is': [14], 'a': [16], 'test': [13]}
After {'This': [3], 'is': [14], 'a': [16], 'test': [13]}
```

but the more principled way in my opinion is using handy objects like `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`.

Comment: thank you sir for reaching out. I'm really sorry sir still learning these things. how can I reuse this saved file using pickle and assume there values to "onehot_repr". when we do the prediction we need to reuse these same values in given sentences.

Comment: did you use `UNK`, `PAD` or any other `special token`? @noob